# Personal Internet Facing SharePoint Site

Tags: internet-sites

I've been interested in having my own personal site for some time, and being that my job is with SharePoint, I am pretty familiar with it.  That being said, I have no idea if SP would suit well as a personal Internet facing website.

If it does or if it doesn't where should I be looking into for webhosting and any other requirements for setting this up?  This doesn't completely belong here, but if it works I would like to work with SP as I'm quite comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have [Office 365 personal](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy-office-365-personal-FX104160403.aspx) package which comes with a site, 1 TB one drive storage, email account and etc... Also you will be able to tryout somethings in that site as well. Also 60 Skype world minutes free. It's 7 USD per month or 70 USD per year.

It depends on your requirement. If you want to maintain just a blog, buy a domain through Google or WordPress and create a simple site at almost no cost.

Comment: Awesome, that helps quite a bit.  So what are the differences between this and something like [NetworkSolutions](http://www.networksolutions.com/web-hosting/sharepoint/index.jsp) besides the storage?

Comment: There are many. Given O365 is a Microsoft product, it always stays up to date. Then technical support, availability, Lync, Exchange Server all at one price.

Comment: Haven't had time til now to look at this again.  So how do I set up my domain to an O365 Personal account?  Looking through the site I don't see any options for it.

Answer (score 1):

Personal site on SharePoint can be a lot of fun indeed. Here I have a little inspirational article for you:

- [Public blog on SharePoint](http://markeev.com/Articles/public-blog-on-sharepoint.aspx)

This is my post about my own blog. I believe it has some useful tips for those who want to take same road (main advice would be: forget the SP blog template). For me, building blog on SP was a lot of fun and great experience. So I think it's definitely worth a try!

Hosting might be considered a bit of a problem, but if you work with SharePoint seriosly, having a personal o365 portal is very convenient for all kinds of small tests. Virtual machines eat a lot of resources and generally a pain in the a$$ with all these reboots. Myself, for many years already I semiunconsciosly avoid VMs whenever possible and prefer cloud.